# How to define frequency of SyncAdapter updates on android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, frequency, android-syncadapter

ContentProvided defined for synchronization is dummy (in accordance with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649808/syncadapter-without-a-contentprovider/4650589#4650589)).

Comment: Looks like addPeriodicSync is a key, but it requires API 8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If API > 8, (95% of devices) use `ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync()`

If API = 7, (5.5% of devices as of Mar 2102) create a service with a periodic timer callback, and call `ContentResolver.requestSync()`.

API < 6 does not support syncAdapter, so no worries.

Comment: Thanks. API = 7. So, looks like there is no much sense for me to support synchronization thru SyncAdapter - Service would be enough (I need to sync data with my local database, it can be done without account).

Comment: You should definitely be using a SyncAdapter and ContentProvider.  Just because you're not sharing externally doesn't mean you should be doing it all by hand.  ContentProvider is a great, clean interface and ensures all your database work happens in a background thread.  Prevents ANR errors etc.  Keep at it, it's the way to go.

Comment: Now nearly every device is API 8 or higher.  You will probably have a few users with older versions, but very few and they will likely upgrade soon.

Comment: If I don't use any function for syncing, what would be the behavior of it? Also, is it possible to define it in XML ? What if I want to disable syncing?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I don't understand your questions.  Post a proper new question instead of comment replies and I'll work on answering it.

Comment: @jcwenger i meant, what if i don't call "addPeriodicSync"? in which cases would the "onPerformSync" be called? how often? the second question was if it's possible to use "addPeriodicSync" in xml instead of in code. the third question was how to disable the syncing altogether via xml .

Comment: Post a proper new question instead of comment replies.