# Running simple syncdapter with stub authenticator and stub provider

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am trying to implement a simple sync adapter with stub provider (which I got from answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649808/syncadapter-without-a-contentprovider) question) and stub authenticator . And for authentication I used basic [sync adapter example](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BasicSyncAdapter.zip) provided by google . 
On perform sync I just want to print a msg on log cat

```
   public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String s, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.i("SyncAdapter", "Sync adapter testing");
    }
```

and from main activity I just called the sync adapter like this

```
 mAccount = GenericAccountService.GetAccount();
    mResolver.addPeriodicSync(
            mAccount,
            AUTHORITY,
            Bundle.EMPTY,
            10);
```

But it doesn't working though it creates a authenticator account , but the log messages are not showing .

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are checking the right logs, the logs sync adapter creates are not posted under your application, but under the sync adapter it self.

Comment: And almost 3 years later somebody is having the same issue. How can i debug the sync adapter process? I tried to debug only by a filter in logcat  (Just Log message: "My Message", for example), but i am having no luck.