# android get picasa image URLs

Tags: android, android-gallery, picasa

We are working on an application that needs / wants to act like the stock Gallery app in that it shows images from the SD card, as well as images from picasa.

I realize I could obtain credentials from the user / use oauth / whatever, then access the picasa web service API, and so on. however, I'm wondering if there's any shortcut. requiring the user to log in to picasa each time they fire up the app is a real downer. even asking for the creds one time makes people worry.

any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't most picasa users have their Google account information stored on the device already?

Comment: yes, but i'm asking how to 1) get that information and 2) how to use it to gain access to the user's picasa photos.

Answer (score 1):

You can request permission to use the Google account using the `AccountManager` API. See [What should I use Android AccountManager for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720315/should-i-use-android-accountmanager) for more details on this.

Comment: that does not apply. that perm is to allow your app to create / manage an account. it does give access to the creds of existing accounts (obviously).

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't entirely clear. I was recommending looking more into the AccountManager API, not recommending the specific permission mentioned in the referenced SA post. As Google supposedly dogfoods the SDK APIs for all their applications, you should be able to use the existing Google account on the device to authenticate if you request the right permissions. Unfortunately, I don't know what that is, but I suspect the answer lies in the Android source. I'll post more if I find it.