# Trying to add a gmail account programmaticaly in android but getting error "caller uid 10040 is different than the authenticator's uid"

Tags: android, gmail, accountmanager, google-account

There is an emial application in android that allows to add email account. How can I add a gmail account in that application programmatically?

I used  this link [Add account automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664987/add-account-automatically) but 
 got SecurityException "caller uid 10040 is different than the authenticator's uid".

I used that code with

```
        Account account = new Account("my id@gmail.com", "com.example.addaccount.account");
```

Where "com.example.addaccount.account" is package name of my application, and I added authenticator.xml file in a folder named xml, with same package name android:accountType="com.example.addaccount.account".

But I am getting error "caller uid 10043 is different than the authenticator's uid". Can any one please tell me, what am I missing? I just added the xml file and wrote that code to add account, do I need to refer to that xml somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This method return the android market gmail account

```
public String getAccount(){
    String email=null;
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    for (Account account : accounts) {
         email=accounts[0].toString(); 
    }
    return email;
}
```

also add this in manifest.xml

```
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```