# Example using Android Account Manager

Tags: android, accountmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I use Android AccountManager for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720315/what-should-i-use-android-accountmanager-for)

I was wondering if there are any simple examples, using Android account manager, so that I can understand it better.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Are you trying to gain access to an existing account on the device, or define a type of account for a custom service that you want to expose to the system?

Comment: actually I want to just understand account manager(what all can be done). Resources on net are sparse, so I thought if I can check an  example..

Comment: I think this a to vague question need to clarify it more