# Android Account Manager

Tags: android, user-accounts

I had some queries regarding account manager in android.

1) How SSO is supported in account service.

2) How Sync services use accounts from account service.

3) How account is managed (i.e Add , Delete, Authenticate, Re-Authenticate etc.)

4) Dependency of 3rd party.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720315/should-i-use-android-accountmanager

Comment: I saw this, what I did not understand is how exactly authentication is done? I mean should an app do it or we can have to write separate pluggable interfaces. I mean where exactly is the logic for authentication(URL,formation, Signing and encoding the URL etc...)

Comment: Look for Android Accounts Manager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Android AtLeap library which has helper classes for Account Authenticator. Here it is https://github.com/blandware/android-atleap