# Accounts from Email application not listed

Tags: android, android-account

I have a method in my application which populates an array with account information.
The problem is I can't get the account details stored in Email application (POP3/IMAP).
Is there any way to list the accounts that are created with Email application.

Here is my code:

```
 Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccounts();
  for (Account account : accounts) {
        String EmailID = account.name;
        String Type =account.type;
        Acntlist.add(EmailID);
        Acntlist1.add(Type);
   }
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720315/what-should-i-use-android-accountmanager-for

Comment: @RoystonPinto: Thanks. But,The accounts added from Email Application is not listed in `Accounts & Sync settings`. Is there any way to retrieve the non-listed accounts using `ContentProvider` ?

Comment: No, this is saved in the private space of these applications. They are not added to Database accessed by ContentProvider.