# Android AccountManager :Which account is being used?

Tags: android, authentication, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter, accountmanager

I am using android account manager for my app. It allows multiple accounts and every account has it's own specific data.

What I want to know is;

- How to determine which account is being used by account manager
- Is there a way to set specific account in account manager as current one

I'll be using content provider (single class for multiple tables) with syncAdapter to Upload/Download data from a Laravel REST API.

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html . There are plenty of guides out there with examples on how to add . The first results that google returns is http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/ .

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720315/what-should-i-use-android-accountmanager-for . Most of the basics are well documented here. If you have specific question then please update.

Comment: I just want to know, how to determine which account is being used in multi accout app. Rest my app is working fine with authenticator/syncadapter/content provider.

Comment: Which account is being used where ? The AccountManager just provides APIs to manage accounts. There is no concept of current or default for it

Comment: IN Application Where else? 
Suppose. I have 2 gmail accounts. When i access the app. it shows me both accounts . I select one of them . THen it loads emails related to that specific account. 
I want to do the same, as users of my app has access to different data. So when some user makes a choice of its accout i can access the name of the account myself. but do i have programmatically change the db/user files etc. Thats why i want to know if there is  a way to set/get the Current account being used.

Comment: Ok. it means , after validating the account being picked by user, i must change the files myself.

Comment: the data should all the there always. you need to query appropriately based on your UI selection. The `AccountManager` is not going to do anything about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information and clarification by @RocketRandom , it is clear that Account Manager just provides the service.
The user/app developer should work out the proper way to handle the accounts.

For my specific problem (Multi User Login), i present user with a selection list(Custom) which allows me to pass on specific user data to SyncAdapter, which in turn load the account related Sqlite db (I am using separate db for each user).